# $.each raises error (e is undefined) in Firefox but works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cDVQP/1/

If you have both Chrome and Firefox you can see that it works as expected in Chrome but in Firefox Firebug console you get "TypeError: e is undefined"
On JSFiddle the error appears as "TypeError: obj is undefined"

I've spent hours hunting down this bug and trying to figure it out and finally gave up and came here. What's causing it?

Here is the full code to test:

```
<html>
<body>

  <div id="x"></div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      getVideos('cats');
    });

    function getVideos(query){
      var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=2&q='+query+'&regionCode=us&type=video&fields=items(id)&key=AIzaSyCCOnozV0lEfnjfMTjpc4TFExAeIGJ6Fh0';
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
          appendVideos(data);
        }
      });
    }

    function appendVideos(data){
      // works here
      console.log(data);

      // but not in $.each
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
        $('#x').append(item.id.videoId + '<br>');
      });
    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, when I alert (data.items) I get undefined in FF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looks like the data is being passed into the appendVideos as a string and not an object like you think. I did a

```
for(i in data) {
    alert(i+'='+data[i]);
}
```

And it's acting like a string.

This fixed it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data){
      appendVideos(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: We all come across situations where we miss the obvious. FYI, if you `alert(data)` it should return `[Object]` if your data is being properly parsed into a JSON object.

Comment: I don't know which browser is more right here. I think Chrome is wrong here to implicitly parse to JSON. If I had seen the error is both browsers, I would have found the bug sooner. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

It's all a guess. jQuery is doing the guessing and it looks like Chrome figured out the MIME type correctly based on the content. I almost never include the dataType. I might start.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, why not just use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=2&q='+query+'&regionCode=us&type=video&fields=items(id)&key=AIzaSyCCOnozV0lEfnjfMTjpc4TFExAeIGJ6Fh0';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) 
{
    appendVideos(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There error is found on line 622 of jQuery 1.9.1 It is caused by the Object that you are passing is being `undefined`. Line 622 makes a call to `obj.length` and since `undefined` has no property called length it throws and error.

Adding `dataType: 'JSON'` to your `$.ajax` request will fix this error

Comment: But this is more to do with the browser than jQuery, no?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery isn't automatically parsing the response as json in Firefox, rather it's interpreting it as a string.

If you change your success function to the following it should work:

```
success: function(data){
    if(typeof(data) === 'string') {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    }

    appendVideos(data);
}
```

Comment: Setting the datatype as JSON in the ajax request forces it to do so.